# Drag bubble in d3js bubblechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I was going through an example of d3js bubblechart .
Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/49L6uj7s/

Can someone please explain why 198 is used for calculating euclideanDistance :

```
var euclideanDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((d.px - 198), 2) + Math.pow((d.py - 198), 2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The euclidean distance that is being calculated in the example is the distance between the middle of the circle you are dragging and the parent container.

Once calculated, it is used to keep the child circle within the parent circle.

A check is made to see if the drag position is outside the parent and if so, it sets the x and y of the dragged object to stay at the edge of the parent:

```
  function dragmove(d) {
        var euclideanDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((d.px - 198), 2) + Math.pow((d.py - 198), 2));

        if(euclideanDistance > 198 - d.radius){
            d.px = d.px - 198;
            d.py = d.py - 198;

            var radians = Math.atan2(d.py, d.px);

            d.px = Math.cos(radians) * (198 - d.radius) + 198;
            d.py = Math.sin(radians) * (198 - d.radius) + 198;
        }
    }
```

The parent circle is actually a rectangle thats 400*400px with a 50% border radius, hence the 198 (200 px with a 2px border).

Comment: Ok..Got it . Thanks a lot @StaceyBurns